# Should I worry that my bachelor's degree will be revoked because I only completed half my internship hours?

Tags: degree, bachelor

This happened in 2016. In my college where I got my bachellor degree (no thesis required), one of the requirements to get that degree is to have 600 trainee hours at a company. The company send a letter to the college which states that I only worked for 300 hours as a trainee (which is correct).

However, Now I've just remembered that the college considerated the 300 hours as 600 hours. Should I worry that they will find out their mistake and revoke my bachelor degree?

I remember that I told the secretary that they were making a mistake but she didnt care and told me to go away.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 2):

**You shouldn't worry about it.** The general principal is that the dean of the college that signed your diploma felt you had met the requirements. It would be unusual to second guess that decision years after the fact without a compelling reason (like new evidence of fraud).

We've had a [lot](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124106/will-the-phd-degree-be-retracted-if-the-thesis-is-found-to-be-not-novel) [of](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/123891/can-my-university-revoke-my-degree-after-it-was-granted-due-to-corporate-data) [questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102999/can-a-department-revoke-a-degree-once-granted-by-the-university) about degree revocation recently. Everyone agrees that this is extremely rare, and almost non-existent when the student acted in good faith and the university deliberately issued the degree. It is difficult to imagine a mechanism where the university would even notice the discrepancy, much less care enough to pursue the matter.

By the way, I recently gave the opposite advice to [a similar question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124325/i-left-college-in-the-last-semester-did-not-finish-but-the-college-transferr/124326#124326). But the situations are a little different--in the other case, there was a question about whether the degree had been awarded, and why it was awarded. Your degree was issued according to the normal process.

Comment: there was a woman in my country who falsified her highschool diploma, she was caught many many years later and the college who admitted her revoked all her degree. Won't that be my case because, both my case and her are administrative errors?

Comment: No, she falsified her high school diploma -- that most  definitely counts as "evidence of fraud" and not "acting in good faith." In your case, it's not clear why they accepted your 300 hours as meeting the internship requirement -- maybe a mistake, maybe some other reason -- but you did not misrepresent anything, and they accepted it, so you should be good. Best to let sleeping dogs lie.

Comment: thanks for the comments, I am not a native english speaker, what does "Best to let sleeping dogs lie" mean?

Comment: from google: "avoid interfering in a situation that is currently causing no problems but might do so as a result of such interference."